# Data no longer numeric after subsetting

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I am trying to subset a dataset based on the TMtClones column in the dataset below. I want to subset YldAll only for TmTClones desiree. However, when I attempt to subset the resulting data is no longer numeric. My data is below:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), Location = c("Khangma", 
"Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", 
"Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", 
"Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", 
"Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma"), TmtClones = 
c("304357.31", 
"306518.1", "306519.64", "399004.19", "399078.11", "395436.8", 
"397196.3", "Desiree", "304357.31", "306518.1", "306519.64", 
"399004.19", "399078.11", "395436.8", "397196.3", "Desiree", 
"304357.31", "306518.1", "306519.64", "399004.19", "399078.11", 
"395436.8", "397196.3", "Desiree"), YldAll = c(10.3, 10.9, 8.5, 
10.2, 9.5, 6.8, 4.8, 8.5, 10.9, 8.7, 9.7, 12, 10.3, 5.3, 5.7, 
8.2, 10.9, 11.9, 4, 10.2, 5, 4.7, 2.5, 7.9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried subsetting in two different ways, as shown in the code below:

```
YldAll.Desiree <- subset(potato.data2, TmtClones == "Desiree", select 
= YldAll)

YldAll.Desiree2 <- potato.data2 %>%
  filter(TmtClones == "Desiree") %>%
  select(YldAll)
```

In both cases, the resulting data is no longer numeric according to is.numeric(), and I get errors when I try to use it. I cannot figure out why, as is.numeric(potato.data2$YldAll) gives TRUE. If I try to coerce YldAll.Desiree or YldAll.Desiree2 to numeric, I get the error - 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

Comment: Is it a dataframe? `str(YldAll.Desiree)`

Comment: cannot reproduce.. output is numeric in my case... `str(YldAll.Desiree)` results in `YldAll: num [1:3] 8.5 8.2 7.9`

Comment: I'm getting numeric from your test data. Maybe there's another problem? Have you tried changing the class to numeric with `mutate` e.g. `YldAll.Desiree2 <- potato.data2 %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%filter(TmtClones == "Desiree") %>% select(YldAll)` ?

Comment: The issue is that your data is a tibble. Other than a data.frame, it will not return a vector but a tibble when subsetting to a single column.

Comment: I got numeric output: `> is.numeric(YldAll.Desiree$YldAll)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @efz Do `library(tibble)` before running the code.

Comment: You could do `potato.data2[potato.data2$TmtClones == "Desiree", "YldAll", drop = TRUE]` as the R gods intended, or simply do not use tibbles or learn how the disciples of Hadley extract a vector from a tibble (the latter I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

data.frame cannot be numeric, because it is a list. Instead matrix can be 2d numeric object. When you call `is.numeric/as.numeric` it should be on the column of the `data.frame` and not on the whole `data.frame`. See example.

```r
potato.data2 <- structure(
  list(
    Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
             2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
             2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), 
    Location = c("Khangma", 
                 "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", 
                 "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", 
                 "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", 
                 "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma", "Khangma"), 
    TmtClones = 
      c("304357.31", 
        "306518.1", "306519.64", "399004.19", "399078.11", "395436.8", 
        "397196.3", "Desiree", "304357.31", "306518.1", "306519.64", 
        "399004.19", "399078.11", "395436.8", "397196.3", "Desiree", 
        "304357.31", "306518.1", "306519.64", "399004.19", "399078.11", 
        "395436.8", "397196.3", "Desiree"), 
    YldAll = c(10.3, 10.9, 8.5, 
               10.2, 9.5, 6.8, 4.8, 8.5, 10.9, 8.7, 9.7, 12, 10.3, 5.3, 5.7, 
               8.2, 10.9, 11.9, 4, 10.2, 5, 4.7, 2.5, 7.9)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -24L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
str(potato.data2)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    24 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ Year     : num  2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
#>  $ Location : chr  "Khangma" "Khangma" "Khangma" "Khangma" ...
#>  $ TmtClones: chr  "304357.31" "306518.1" "306519.64" "399004.19" ...
#>  $ YldAll   : num  10.3 10.9 8.5 10.2 9.5 6.8 4.8 8.5 10.9 8.7 ...
is.numeric(potato.data2)
#> [1] FALSE
is.numeric(potato.data2$YldAll)
#> [1] TRUE


library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
YldAll.Desiree2 <- potato.data2 %>%
  filter(TmtClones == "Desiree") %>%
  select(YldAll)
str(YldAll.Desiree2)
#> tibble [3 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ YldAll: num [1:3] 8.5 8.2 7.9
is.numeric(YldAll.Desiree2)
#> [1] FALSE
is.numeric(YldAll.Desiree2$YldAll)
#> [1] TRUE
```